How to increase maximum limit for completion_tokens in AWS Sagemaker invoke endpoint
I have deployed the meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct model using HuggingFaceModel. The model responds with the full output when I make a call using HuggingFaceModel's predictor method. Here is the Google Colab
However, AWS Sagemaker's invoke endpoint has a maximum limit of completion_tokens as 100 tokens, so when I use this invoke endpoint, the out response stops after 100 tokens.
What am I doing wrong and how can I increase this value please?
Here is the output of the token usage using predict method:
'usage': {'prompt_tokens': 68, 'completion_tokens': 918, 'total_tokens': 986}

Here is the output of the token usage using SageMaker invoke method :
'usage': {'prompt_tokens': 63, 'completion_tokens': 100, 'total_tokens': 163}

For all the prompts the maximum token limit is set to 100 ('completion_tokens': 100)
I tried the solution with predict method of huggingface model and it works.

As per the documentation here, link I re-created the predictor object used for inference.
Code Snippet:
from sagemaker.huggingface.model import HuggingFacePredictor  predictor = HuggingFacePredictor(endpoint_name='your-huggingface-endpoint-name')
